# Why does .htaccess or php.ini overriding /etc/php.ini not work?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I want to adjust the post_max_size and upload_max_filesize without altering /etc/php.ini

PHP Version 5.3.27
root directory: /var/www/html/my_site

Here are the things that I did:

- I added php.ini under html directory (didn't work)

  ```
  memory_limit = 96M
  post_max_size = 64M
  upload_max_filesize = 64M
  ```
- I added .htaccess file under html directory (didn't work)

  ```
  php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
  php_value post_max_size 64M
  ```
- I also added both of them under /my_site directory and none of them worked
- Everytime I add each of them I restart the server
- I also changed php.ini to php5.ini
- I also changed

  ```
  php_value
  ```

  to

  ```
   php5_value
  ```
- Adjusted permission issues

What went wrong?

Comment: Got any error messages with your attempts? Are you running mod_php at all or possibly the cgi/fcgi version?

Comment: I have checked the error in logs saying  PHP Warning:  POST Content-Length of 15799451 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0, referer:

Comment: And how will I know if I'm running a mod_php or cgi/fcgi version?

Comment: You can check if your changes in .htaccess are taking effect by using `ini_get(flag_name)` in your php files. e.g.: `echo ini_get('upload_max_filesize')` would output the value of `upload_max_filesize`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many shared hosts restrict the flags you can use in your .htaccess, and `upload_max_filesize`/`post_max_size` are common ones. If you're on a shared host contact tech support to confirm this.

Comment: What are those flags? Could you please be more specific? thanks!

Comment: It's up to the server administrator as to exactly how they restrict customisation of the apache/php environment. If you're trying to to allow large uploads on your site, `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` are the flags you want (and possibly also `max_execution_time` and `max_input_time`), but often you as a user of their services aren't allowed to change them yourself in an .htaccess file, for security reasons. They'll often increase those values for you if you request it though.

Comment: We have our own server here and have a direct contact with the system administrator to change stuff. As we increase the values of upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in /etc/php.ini it turns out fine but since we don't want to alter the main file we're looking for a way to override it. Do you have any suggestions on what our sys admin could do to help me??

Comment: Isn't the sysadmin paid to fix stuff like this?

Comment: Sure, in that case it sounds like those options are restricted in .htaccess. Have your sysadmin use the `AllowOverride All` directive in your httpd.conf file as per the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html). This will allow those settings in your .htaccess to take effect.

Comment: Alright. I'll try that and let you know how it goes. Thank you!

Comment: @DetectiveDrone No worries!